# Get the output of a remote ssh to local

Tags: ssh, remote, output, tee, standard

I'm able to get the output of a failing `lp` command from a remotehost to my local script like below:

```
until ssh -q root@remotehost 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /root/moht/Printed/`basename "$FILE"`' 2>&1 | tee /home/printererror.log
do
echo "Issue is: `cat /home/printererror.log`"

sleep 230

done
```

The issue is the `until` does not loop even if the `lp` command fails.

If I change my `until` code and remove  `2>&1 | tee /home/printererror.log` like below then it works fine and starts looping for failing `lp` command. But like you see I'm unable to grab the error message after removing `tee`

```
until ssh -q root@remotehost 'lp -d Brother_HL_L2350DW_series /root/moht/Printed/`basename "$FILE"`'
```

I want both the `until` to loop for failing `lp` command while logging the respecting failing messages to local `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `until` is considering the exit status of `tee`.

Looking at your code it's not at all obvious why you should need `tee`, though, so I'd suggest you just remove it

```
until ssh -q root@remotehost 'lp …' >/home/printererror.log 2>&1
do
    : …
done
```